# How to pass a boolean parameter from component to VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I want to pass a boolean parameter from component to VF page, so that I can control the flow depending on the value of this parameter. 
I am not getting updated value of boolean parameter on VF page. I am setting this value in a controller of a component. I am getting blank string always.

Code of Page.

```
function resetPriorityAction(abletoUpdatePriority){
    alert(abletoUpdatePriority);
    ....
}

**snip**

<div class="verticalContent priorities">
<apex:repeat value="{!MIR.prioritiesWithAF}" var="priority">
    <div class="verticalContentItem priority {!priority.record.Id}">
        <c:MIRPriorityDetails p="{!priority}" showExtra="{!MIR.hasMainSA}" hidebut="{!isedit}" mir="{!MIR}" />
    </div>
</apex:repeat>
```

Code of Component.

```
<apex:component controller="MIRPriorityDetailController" allowDML="true">
<apex:attribute name="mir" type="MIRObject" description="MIRObject" assignTo="{!mirObj}"/>
<apex:actionFunction name="savepriorityDetail" action="{!SavePriority}" rerender="priority" oncomplete="resetPriorityAction({!mirObj.abletoUpdatePriority});">
    <apex:param value="aoe" name="aoe" assignTo="{!areasOfExpertise}"/>
</apex:actionFunction>
```

Code of MIRPriorityDetailController

```
try{
    update sobj;    
    mirObj.abletoUpdatePriority = 'sucess';     
}
catch(DMLException excp){
    mirObj.abletoUpdatePriority = 'fail';            
}
```

Comment: So VF page `A` using controller `Foo` includes a component `Bar` that does DML in its own controller `MIRPriorityDetailController` and based on the success of the DML, you want to communicate this success state back to controller `A` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show your declaration of the boolean object in your controller. That would be very helpful.

A Boolean will have a value of either 'true' or 'false'. To work around that issue, you likely need to do something along the lines of the following:

```
Boolean result1 = 'false';
if(valueOf(mirObj.abletoUpdatePriority) = 'sucess') result1 = 'true';
else if(valueOf(mirObj.abletoUpdatePriority) = 'fail') result1 = 'false';
```

Depending on the logic in the rest of your controller, you may need to do the opposite like below:

```
if(result1 == 'true') mirObj.abletoUpdatePriority = 'sucess';
else if(result1 == 'false') mirObj.abletoUpdatePriority = 'fail';
```

Without seeing the rest of your controller, I really couldn't say. I hope this at least points you in the correct direction toward solving your issue.